# Why are these words, Judaism, Jews, Hebrew, Ibrani, Judea. Semites refer to jews?

Tags: yehuda

The jews are called by many names. Some names are clear. Israelites, for example, is a name given by Hashem to Jacob and the jews are descendant of that guy.

What about the other names?

Why Hebrew? For example. Is it from Eber?

What about Judaism? From Judah?

Ibrani? Where does that name comes from? Ibrahim? Eber?

And Judea? Is that from Judah again?

I could add semites (from Shem, son of Noah?) but that's really strange.

And why the names are used to call jews (and only jews)? Obviously, assuming the torah is correct, Eber have many descendants than just Israel. Israel has many descendants than just Judah.

Answer (score 1):

Off the cuff, it is important to note that "Ivrim" doesn't just mean "ones from Ever" geographically. Some see it as "ones from across, over, the divide" which is a divide between polytheism and monotheism. [Here](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2005/11/who-is-hebrew.html) is something to read on the word. It also deals with "who is and who isn't".

The place "Judea" is named from the tribal designation of Judah (which is where "Jew" originates with the development working through the kingdom of Judah. I don't know the word "Ibrani" and a quick web search provides nothing useful. Semites is related to Shem, son of Noah. The term was used by the mid 19th century to refer to Jews. References available upon request.

Comment: ibrani is one word used in the bible to describe jews I think. I am indonesian that's a word we use. Perhaps it comes from arabic origin?

Comment: We called the greek Yunani. I wonder where that verb comes from either.

Comment: @JimThio Since "Ibrani" seems Arabic, it may be the Arabic version of "Ivri". Perhaps you are referring to an Arabic translation.

Comment: This is the word ibrani used in indonesian wiki https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahasa_Ibrani

Comment: @JimThio the Hebrew for "Greeks" is "Yevanim" but it is a noun, not a verb.

Comment: @JimThio The site that you point to says "Bahasa Ibrani (/ˈhiːbruː/) (עִבְרִית ʿIvrit, Tentang suara ini [ʔivˈʁit]" which seems to say that it is Ivrit (the Heberew language) in the tranliteration or translation from the language in which the site is written